# Can't seem to figure out equations in Mesh Current Method

Tags: current-measurement

So I've been tasked to use the Mesh Current Method to determine the currents in different meshes using SageMath, and then compare the values with those obtained in Qucs. My problem is that SageMath is not giving the expected values, and therefore I think my equations are wrong. However, I can't figure what exactly is wrong with them...

This is my circuit (From Qucs), alongside with the results obtained for the current going through each probe, from the simulation :

[image: eMy Circuit]

Meshes are indicated by Red Numbers.

And these are my equations:

$$
EQ_{M1} : (I_1 - I_2)R3 + (I_1 - I_3)R1 = IV_{cc1}
$$
$$
EQ_{M2} : (I_2 - I_4)R2 + (I_2 - I_1)R3 = V_{cc1}
$$
$$
EQ_{M3} : (I_3 - I_1)R1 + (I_3 - I_5)R6 + I_3R9 = 0
$$
$$
EQ_{M4} : (I_4 - I_2)R2 + I_4R4 + (I_4 - I_6)R7 = 0
$$
$$ 
EQ_{M5} : (I_5 - I_3)R6 + (I_5 - I_6)R10 + (I_5 - I_7)R8 + I_5R13 = 0
$$
$$
EQ_{M6} : (I_6-I_4)R7 + (I_6-I_5)R10 + (I_6-I_8)R5  = IV_{cc2}
$$
$$
EQ_{M7} : (I_7 - I_5)R8 + (I_7 - I_8)R11 = V_{cc2}
$$
$$
EQ_{M8} : (I_8 - I_6)R5 + I_8R12 + (I_8 - I_7)R11 = 0
$$

Where $$ I_n $$ is the current at mesh n and $$ IV_{ccN} $$ is the current going through Vn.

Could you help me figure out what's wrong with my equations? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks (from the arrows) like you have both clockwise currents and counter clockwise currents.  Typically you only use one or the other (they can always be negative, after all) to keep things simpler.  However, in the equations you always use negatives between them (which implies all are ccw).  If they are as 'arrowed' the M2 equation would have an R3(I2+I1) term instead of an R3(I2-I1) term.

Comment: I've been looking unto that, and you are right (Thank you!): If they are as arrowed (I2 + I1)R3 would be right. The problem is that since something else with my equations is wrong and not giving me the values I would like, I still can't check if my directions are right!

Comment: @Kiwii There are 7 unknown node voltages. The others are directly assignable or are a fixed offset from a known node voltage. So there should be, in the end, 7 equations and 7 unknowns to solve. I also completely disagree with your first equation, just to start out. Using counterclockwise currents throughout, I get \$0\:\textrm{V} - \left(I_1-I_3\right)\cdot R_1 - \left(I_1-I_2\right)\cdot R_3 - V_{I_1} = 0\:\textrm{V}\$ as the loop equation. Note that you say \$IV_{cc1}\$ is a current. But you cannot equate a current to a voltage in your equation; that's a basic dimensional analysis error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier in formulating your equations without making mistakes if you assume all of the loops are either clockwise or counter-clockwise. I'm assuming counter-clockwise for the following equations, which start out by always using the lower left-hand corner of the loop as the starting point and always work around the loop in a counter-clockwise direction:

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_1-I_3\right)\cdot R_1-\left(I_1-I_2\right)\cdot R_3-V_{I_1}&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{1}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_2-I_4\right)\cdot R_2+10\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_2-I_1\right)\cdot R_3&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{2}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_3-I_5\right)\cdot R_6-\left(I_3-I_1\right)\cdot R_1-I_3\cdot R_9 &=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{3}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_4-I_6\right)\cdot R_7-I_4\cdot R_4-\left(I_4-I_2\right)\cdot R_2&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{4}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_5-I_7\right)\cdot R_8-\left(I_5-I_6\right)\cdot R_{10}-\left(I_5-I_3\right)\cdot R_6-I_5\cdot R_{13}&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{5}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_6-I_8\right)\cdot R_5-V_{I_2}-\left(I_6-I_4\right)\cdot R_7-\left(I_6-I_5\right)\cdot R_{10}&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{6}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-\left(I_7-I_8\right)\cdot R_{11}-\left(I_7-I_5\right)\cdot R_8-10\:\textrm{V}&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{7}\\
0\:\textrm{V}-I_8\cdot R_{12}-\left(I_8-I_6\right)\cdot R_5-\left(I_8-I_7\right)\cdot R_{11}&=0\:\textrm{V}\tag{8}
\end{align*}$$

Nominally, this would suggest that you have eight equations with ten unknowns (the eight current loop variables plus \$V_{I_1}\$ and \$V_{I_2}\$.) However, you just happen to also know that \$I_1=10\:\textrm{mA}\$ and that \$I_6=-10\:\textrm{mA}\$. So this is really eight equations and eight unknowns.

You said you know how to use sage. So, if you set up the above equations as eq1 through eq8, you could write the following sage solve expression:

```
solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8],i2,i3,i4,i5,i7,i8,vi1,vi2)
```

Note that I didn't add \$I_1\$ or \$I_6\$ to the list of unknowns to solve for, since those are known (along with the resistor values.)

From that, I get from sage:

```
{i5: -0.00369878505234083,
 i7: -0.00403534757110546,
 i2: 0.00622950819672131,
 vi2: 135.173395904543,
 i8: -0.00337102940293429,
 vi1: -22.0735198044639,
 i3: -0.000762044394627810,
 i4: -0.00442622950819672}
```

Which I'm sure is correct.

Comment: Yes, those are Correct! My problem was not only about a dimensional analysis error but also the way I was thinking of the meshes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kiwii Thanks for the kind comment. Yes, I hoped that working through the details would show you where you went wrong. It sounds as though it did and that you are better now for the result. If so, that makes the effort entirely worth it!

Answer (score 1):

Because mesh 1 has a current source in it (not shared with another mesh) you can just write
$$I_1 = 10\ {\rm mA}$$ 
in place of your first equation.

Similarly, for mesh 6,
$$I_6 = 10\ {\rm mA}.$$

If either of these current sources had been on a branch shared by two meshes, you'd have had to introduce super-meshes.

Comment: I had done that before. My problem was that when I did that, Sage returned "TypeError: cannot evaluate symbolic expression numerically", so what I did is keep equations 1 and 6 as they are and add 2 more equations, Gen1 and Gen2 which did exactly that. In that scenario, it would not give an error, but the answers would still defer from those in Qucs. Is adding those 2 equations wrong?